# How to authenticate from third party API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

For my rails app, I implemented some authentication using twitter and facebook. I used omniauth-facebook and omniauth-twitter gem. Since these

Now for my university project, I have to implement authentication using our university API authentication system also. My question is, should I use omniauth or is there any other gems for this that would be easy to implement? I am confused because, omniauth has built in features for twitter, facebook etc. But for custom authentication, I am not sure how complex it would be. So I am asking which gem would be simpler for this purpose?

Comment: Maybe your university's API is dead simple, or maybe it's totally insane. You'll need to investigate that first. Use the Twitter auth as an example and write your own plugin for Omniauth.

Comment: You can [create you own OmniAuth Strategy](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Strategy-Contribution-Guide), just research your university API and see how it works.

Comment: Completely depends on your university API, do you have documentation to it?